# Connecting to Oracle in Codeigniter (undefined constant OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS)

Tags: php, codeigniter, oracle11g

im kind of a n00b to Oracle db's, but when i set my dbdriver in codeigniter to oci8, i get the following error, which is weird, providing the extension is enabled in the php.ini file.

I get the following error.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS - assumed 'OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS'

Filename: database/DB.php

Line Number: 82

Answer (score 0):

You should install/enable the oci8 extension.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php

Comment: That install guide is pretty vague.

Comment: The link is useful as it answers the issue to the problem. The oci8 php extension needs to be installed.